# Perl Regex with variables not matching the same text

Tags: regex, perl

Could someone explain to me why the following prints "fail"?  And what the workaround is?

```
my $test1 = "/k?user";
my $test2 = "/k?user";
if ($test1 =~ m/$test2/) {
    print "match";
}
else {
    print "fail";
}
```

If I change `$test1` and `$test1` to `"/k?"`, the match works.

Clearly it has something to do with text following the `?`. But, the variables I am trying to match have question marks in them, and I would rather not have to take everything apart, match the pieces, and then reconstruct everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`?` is a [special character in a regex](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quoting-metacharacters).  Use [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html):

```
my $test1 = "/k?user";
my $test2 = quotemeta "/k?user";
if ($test1 =~ m/$test2/) {
    print "match";
}
else {
    print "fail";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To (only) match

```
/k?user
```

one needs to use the pattern

```
^/k\?user\z
```

because "`?`" doesn't match itself in a regex pattern. You need to escape it (use "`\?`") for it to match a "`?`", and escaping the special characters (such as "`?`") can be done using [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html).

```
my $str = '/k?user';
my $pat = quotemeta($str);
/^$pat\z/
```

`quotemeta` can also be accessed via `\Q..\E` in double-quoted string literals and regex pattern literals.

```
my $str = '/k?user';
/^\Q$str\E\z/
```

(The solution previously suggested by toolic would also match "`!/k?userf`".)

Comment: \Q...\E is rather helpful....maybe more so than `quotemeta`.  although i will have to give the "accepted answer" to toolic because he pointed out that `?` is a special character in a regex, which was the source of my ignorance

Comment: I did mention it was a special character too, but I can be more explicit if you want.